# How to cancel vertical space before the multicols environment?

Tags: spacing

How to cancel the space between '\begin{multicols}' and the paragraph above?

[image: the code]

[image: the display mode]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide complete, compilable but small document, which we can copy and test in our computers as it is (you can copy code from your editor and past here). Image of code is not useful.

Comment: Try \multicolsep=0pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative `\vspace*` just before beginning the `multicols` environment:

```
2. Find the Maclaurin expansion of the following functions:
\vspace*{-0.5\multicolsep}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\quad(i) $f(x) = e^x$;\\
\quad(ii) $f(x) = \sin x$;\\
\quad(iii) $f(x) = \cos x$;\\
\quad(iv) $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$;\\
\end{multicols}
```

It may be better to use an `enumerate` environment to use automatic numbering

Comment: Is there any way to modify the multicols environment so that it incorporate this negative space automatically?

Comment: @JoãoJúnior the `multicol` package documentation has the length `\multicolsep` default as `\multicolsep = 12pt plus 4pt minus 3pt` so you could adjust this by using `\setlength{\multicolsep}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1.5pt}` or whatever length you like. As I understand, when you use a multicols environment, \multicolsep is the vertical space added at the beginning and at the end, so redefining \multicosep will affect both the vertical space as a multicols environment begins, and also when it ends.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is written as `12pt plus 4pt minus 3pt` instead of something like `1in`?